# How to Get Value from Crystal Report Formula Field programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How to Get Value from Crystal Report Formula Field programmatically in C#??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FormulaFieldDefinition totalValue = reportDoc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["totValue"];
```